# How to test if someone died twice and then put them in creative with invisiblite x in command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am doing a minigame map, and there are a couple events I want to set-up:

- If someone dies twice they will be eliminated and put into creative with invisibility X
- If all of a persons wool is captured, and placed on an enemy stand, the owner of the wood is eliminated.

I do not have a scoreboard set up yet, but if someone could tell me how to do what I said above that would be great.

[image: Senario]

Comment: Welcome to the site cman! Your question in it's original format was hard to read and unclear, so I've cleaned it up for you. Question clarity is really important for getting good answers to your questions. Additionally, you should really include some detail on what your mini-game is, to make your question easier to understand. The quality of the answers you receive will be a lot higher if you give us more detail about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward once you are used to all of the commands required for scoreboard related things (seriously, there's a lot).

First of all, we need to set up a "Deaths" objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
```

This will keep track of player deaths, and increment automatically when the player dies. Now, we want to put players with a Deaths score of 2 in spectator mode. To do this, I'm going to use the `@a` selector, with

```
/gamemode 3 @a[score_Deaths_min=2,m=0]
```

What this command does is puts all players who are currently in survival mode and have a deaths score of at least 2 into spectator mode. That part is pretty straightforward.

The next bit is... a little trickier (mainly because I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish specifically). But for this, you're going to want a few `/testforblock` commands. The syntax for this is as follows:

```
/testforblock X Y Z tileName dataValue dataTag
```

This command outputs a redstone signal via comparator if the condition is true when the command block receives a pulse.

For example, let's say I wanted to see if there was an orange wool block at (0,64,23). The command for this would be

```
/testforblock 0 64 23 minecraft:wool 1
```

In the case of wool, the data value corresponds to the color of the wool. See [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool#Data_values) on the Minecraft Wiki for a reference.

You can use a few of these with an AND gate of some variety, and you can test for as many of these conditions as you like.

Oh! Also, to reset the game, you're going to want to clear out the death counter (otherwise things won't work properly when you restart). To do this, use this command:

```
/scoreboard players set @a Deaths 0
```

What this does is sets the deaths score of all players to 0, allowing the game to restart.

Answer (score 0):

set scoreboard to deaths, detect if someone died twice, if true, send redstone inpulse to a command block that puts them in spec. mode(new to 1.8).